# use method of value for the condition of numpy where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

let's say you have this data frame:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame( data =    [ '2014-04-07 10:55:35.087000+00:00',
                               '2014-04-07 13:59:37.251500+00:00',
                               '2014-04-02 13:23:59.629000+00:00',
                               '2014-04-07 12:17:48.182000+00:00',
                               '2014-04-06 17:00:23.912000+00:00'],
                    columns = ['timestamp'],
                    dtype = np.datetime64
                    )
```

and you want to create a new column where the values are 1 if the timestamp is a weekday or 0 if it is not. Then I would run something like this:

```
 df['weekday'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.weekday() < 5 else 0 )
```

So far so good. However, in my case **I have about 10 million rows of such timestamp values and it just takes forever to run**. So, I looked around for vectorization options and I found `numpy.where()`. But, of course, this does not work: `np.where(df['timestamp'].weekday() < 5, 1, 0)`

So, is there a way to access the .weekday() method of the timestamps when using numpy.where or is there any other way to produce the weekday column when having 10 million rows? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.dayofweek`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html#pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek) / [`Series.dt.weekday`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html) with [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['weekday'] = df['timestamp'].dt.dayofweek.lt(5).astype(int)
print(df)
                   timestamp  weekday
0 2014-04-07 10:55:35.087000        1
1 2014-04-07 13:59:37.251500        1
2 2014-04-02 13:23:59.629000        1
3 2014-04-07 12:17:48.182000        1
4 2014-04-06 17:00:23.912000        0
```

I recommend you see: [`when should I ever want to use apply in my code`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code)

We could also use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['weekday'] = np.where(df['timestamp'].dt.dayofweek.lt(5), 1, 0)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Many thanks. I was not aware of those .dt and .lt methods of Series. I will read more about them and definitely start using them more.